# How to use evert/sitemap yii2 without using composer?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

hi i want to add evert/sitemap to my project to create my website sitemap.
i downloaded sitemap-php-master zip from https://github.com/evert/sitemap-php and extract it into vendor.
i added below code to `composer.json`

```
"require": {.., "evert/sitemap-php",}
```

then i added to `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` below code

```
'evert\\sitemap-php\\' => array($vendorDir . '/evert/sitemap-php'),
```

and add below code to `yiisoft/extensions`

```
<?
.
.
.
    'evert/sitemap-php' => array (
    'name' => 'evert/sitemap-php',
    'version' => '2',
    'alias' => array (
        '@evert/sitemap-php' => $vendorDir . '/evert/sitemap-php',
    ),
),
?>
```

how can i use this sitemap in my reports?
i should add sitemap in my controllers/ReportsController?

Comment: Use this instead https://github.com/himiklab/yii2-sitemap-module or just Google 'yii2 sitemap'. What you're doing there is just a mess.

Comment: we should add file to vendor?

Comment: Add `"himiklab/yii2-sitemap-module" : "*"` to your composer json file. Then from the command line (in the same directory) run `php composer.phar update` that'll install it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use the composer installed in the system.

```
cd /var/www/projectx/
# if you are running with phar file
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist evert/sitemap
#if you run with exe
composer require --prefer-dist evert/sitemap
```

Or you can add to composer.json file in the root of your project.

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": ">=4.1.4 <7.0",
        "flow/jsonpath": "*",
        "evert/sitemap": "*"
},
```